# Joining various summaries in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have dozens of variables that I need to operate on by group, with different instructions to be done depending on the variable, usually as per the name of the variable, with a few ad hoc changes and renaming here and there.

A reprex using a modified diamonds dataset for illustration is below:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamond_renamed <- diamonds %>% 
  rename(size_x = x, size_y = y, size_z = z) %>% 
  rename(val_1 = depth, val_2 = table)


diamond_summary <-  bind_cols(diamond_renamed %>% 
                               group_by(cut, color, clarity) %>% 
                               summarise(
                                 cost = sum(price)
                               ), 
                             diamond_renamed %>%
                             group_by(cut, color, clarity) %>%
                               summarise_at(
                                 vars(contains("size")), 
                                 funs(median(.))
                                            ),
                             diamond_renamed %>%
                             group_by(cut, color, clarity) %>% 
                               summarise_at(
                                 vars(contains("val")),
                                 funs(mean(.))
                                 )
                             )

diamond_summary    
#> # A tibble: 276 x 15
#> # Groups:   cut, color [?]
#>    cut   color clarity   cost cut1  color1 clarity1 size_x size_y size_z
#>    <ord> <ord> <ord>    <int> <ord> <ord>  <ord>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Fair  D     I1       29532 Fair  D      I1         7.32   7.20   4.70
#>  2 Fair  D     SI2     243888 Fair  D      SI2        6.13   6.06   3.99
#>  3 Fair  D     SI1     247854 Fair  D      SI1        6.08   6.04   3.93
#>  4 Fair  D     VS2     112822 Fair  D      VS2        6.04   6      3.65
#>  5 Fair  D     VS1      14606 Fair  D      VS1        5.56   5.58   3.66
#>  6 Fair  D     VVS2     32463 Fair  D      VVS2       4.95   4.84   3.31
#>  7 Fair  D     VVS1     13419 Fair  D      VVS1       4.92   5.03   3.28
#>  8 Fair  D     IF        4859 Fair  D      IF         4.68   4.73   2.88
#>  9 Fair  E     I1       18857 Fair  E      I1         6.18   6.14   4.03
#> 10 Fair  E     SI2     325446 Fair  E      SI2        6.28   6.20   3.95
#> # ... with 266 more rows, and 5 more variables: cut2 <ord>, color2 <ord>,
#> #   clarity2 <ord>, val_1 <dbl>, val_2 <dbl>
```

This yields the desired result: a dataset with the grouped summaries... but it also repeats the grouped variables. It's also not great to have to repeat the group_by code itself everytime... but I'm not sure how else to do it. It may also not be the most efficient use of `summarise`. How can we avoid that repetition, make this code better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `mutate` instead of `summarize` in the initial steps and add those columns in the `group_by`

```
diamond_renamed %>%
   group_by(cut, color, clarity) %>% 
   group_by(cost = sum(price), add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(contains("size")), median) %>% 
   group_by_at(vars(contains("size")), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(contains("val")), mean)
# A tibble: 276 x 9
# Groups:   cut, color, clarity, cost, size_x, size_y [?]
#   cut   color clarity   cost size_x size_y size_z val_1 val_2
#   <ord> <ord> <ord>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Fair  D     I1       29532   7.32   7.20   4.70  65.6  56.8
# 2 Fair  D     SI2     243888   6.13   6.06   3.99  64.7  58.6
# 3 Fair  D     SI1     247854   6.08   6.04   3.93  64.6  58.8
# 4 Fair  D     VS2     112822   6.04   6      3.65  62.7  60.3
# 5 Fair  D     VS1      14606   5.56   5.58   3.66  63.2  57.8
# 6 Fair  D     VVS2     32463   4.95   4.84   3.31  61.7  58.8
# 7 Fair  D     VVS1     13419   4.92   5.03   3.28  61.7  64.3
# 8 Fair  D     IF        4859   4.68   4.73   2.88  60.8  58  
# 9 Fair  E     I1       18857   6.18   6.14   4.03  65.6  58.1
#10 Fair  E     SI2     325446   6.28   6.20   3.95  63.4  59.5
# ... with 266 more rows
```

NOTE: The grouping columns 'cut', 'color', 'clarity' are not repeated here as in the OP's post.  So, it is only 9 columns instead of 15

Comment: Thank you akrun, that seems to work! I'm just a bit confused by the need to add `group_by_at` after `mutate`, why is that necessary? What is it doing?

Comment: @FonsMA  `mutate` replaces the values of columns that have 'size' with `median` value grouped by 'cost', 'cut', color' clarity'.  Then use those columns have 'median' also in the grouping variable (here the median value is repeated for each group) and when you do the `summarize` these columns (summarized output) will also be present in the output

Comment: Thanks akrun, so I understand the code has to add every variable that has been created to the grouping variables subset; I'm not sure I understand the specifics bu there's a logic to that; thank you!

Comment: @FonsMA  If you split the code into pieces and run step by step, check the output, you will understand it more clearly.  ie. after running the first two lines, then run the third one and check what changes it made